# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error using gSOAP

Tags: c++, objective-c, ipad, ios5, gsoap

I´m really stuck with this issue... and i hope you can help me out here.

I'm developing an iPad app for a company, that requires to use secured SOAP web services... not the perfect combination! i know, the thing is that taking a look around google, i found that the "best" thing to do was making a WS client using gSOAP and that´s what i did! now i have the client for one of those WS in C++.

When i try to call one of the methods of the WS, and build the app... this is what happens:

```
Ld /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akcairabnqiunvddtmwphaispprl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app/App normal i386
cd /Users/me/iOS/App

setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6

setenv PATH '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk 
-L/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akcairabnqiunvddtmwphaispprl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator 
-L/Users/me/iOS/App -F/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akcairabnqiunvddtmwphaispprl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator 
-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks 
-filelist /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akcairabnqiunvddtmwphaispprl/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/i386/App.LinkFileList 
-mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 
-framework SenTestingKit -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -ldataSOAPlibDev 
-o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akcairabnqiunvddtmwphaispprl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app/App

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/me/iOS/App/libdataSOAPlibDev.a,
```

file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

    'soap::soap()', referenced from:
  -[ViewContratosController viewDidLoad] in ViewContratosController.o
  '_soap_init_LIBRARY_VERSION_REQUIRED_20808', referenced from:
  -[ViewContratosController viewDidLoad] in ViewContratosController.o
 'soap_call_ns1__obtenerPais(soap*, char const*, char const*, ns2__paisFile*,     
  ns1__obtenerPaisResponse&)', referenced from:
  -[ViewContratosController viewDidLoad] in ViewContratosController.o
 'soap::~soap()', referenced from:
  -[ViewContratosController viewDidLoad] in ViewContratosController.o
 'ns2__paisFile::soap_default(soap*)', referenced from:
  ns2__paisFile::ns2__paisFile() in ViewContratosController.o
 'vtable for ns2__paisFile', referenced from:
  ns2__paisFile::ns2__paisFile() in ViewContratosController.o
```

**NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.**
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The NOTE may tell the problem... but i don´t know how to solve it... any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you took a library for iPAd (ARM architecture) and tried to build to the simulator (i386 architecture). Try building to the actual device instead.

The hint for me was:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/me/iOS/App/libdataSOAPlibDev.a, file
>   was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
>   (i386)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick answer! i´ve been working on building the libdataSOAPlibDev.a library in the same architecture of the main project, but the problem didn´t dissapear! The good thing is that i realized that i was missing some cpp files in the "Compile Sources" for the Target of the Static Library (libdataSOAPlibDev.a)... i have to say, that this library contains the files generated by gSOAP (.h, .cpp, and .xml). Now the issue is that i have a new error: this time is: <code>ld: duplicate symbol soap_instantiate_std__string</code>... this is duplicated... but built by gSOAP! :((

Answer (score -1):

OK! i solved it including (**not** importing) the headers and the nsmap generated by gSOAP in the .mm file where i´m trying to consume the WS...

```
#include "soapH.h"
#include "soapStub.h"
#include "soapdataServiceSoapBindingProxy.h"
#include "dataServiceSoapBinding.nsmap"
```

If you are going to make a static library out of a WS Client created by gSOAP, be REALLY careful with the "**Build Phases**" of the library Project... add carefully the **headers** and the **compile sources**!

After that... import to your iOS proyect the *"lib.a"* with the *headers* and the *XMLs* under the same folder! and call the WS doing something like this:

```
dataServiceSoapBinding service;
ns2__countryFile country;
struct ns1__getCountryResponse response;

country.idCountry = 11;

if(service.ns1__getCountry(&country, response) == SOAP_OK) {
    NSLog(@"ok");
} else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR");
}
```

I hope this may help anybody... because i had such a hard time figuring this out... and didn´t find much info about it!

:)